# Origin not following its own mesh

Tags: origin

I modeled and rigged a body which has a wire wrapped around the leg , a part of the wire is hanging.
[image: Model]

The top hook has no issue with its origin or empty but the bottom hook does.

I hooked each ends of the wire with empties.

[EmptyHookedToObject](https://youtu.be/KdD4sgW9da8?si=BtvtxUem1NgM7lFG)

Each hooks has 2 modifiers in the following order:

1. Subdivision
2. Armature

Here are the hanging wire's modifiers:[HangingWire'sModifiers](https://youtu.be/OvhUV8SUyX0?si=ojrCDp9_hwD07TvZ)

[HookObject'sModifiers](https://youtu.be/oD3kVjxTQhg?si=OaoV58L853yuramy)

The top hook has no issue with its origin or empty but the bottom hook does.

When I manually bend the leg, the wire does not follow along.
[EmptyNotFollowingItsHookedObject](https://youtu.be/U13bady1jBE?si=EVHOVHSg_JeJ7Pd9)

I animated the bending motion and noticed that one of the hook's origin does not follow its mesh.
[OriginNotFollowingItsOwnMesh](https://youtu.be/UfgnrJmMad4?si=0JaFjstlnX2zH9DZ)

However, when I manually move the hook the origin, the empty and the wire follows the motion.

I want the other end of the wire to follow the little box patented to the body's armature.

I really need help, thank you so much

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file (remove the parts that are not useful): https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Armature Deform modifier deforms the mesh inside the object, that's why the mesh moves but not the object origin. Instead of parenting your hook to your mesh object, parent it to the bone.

Select the hook, then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> select the armature, <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> into pose mode, select the bone, and hit <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > Parent to Bone.

On another note, instead of using empties to hook onto, I think you could use bones instead. Especially if you need to export the rig and its animations later on, you need to use only bones and shape keys, all the rest is pretty much not well-supported if at all.

Comment: Thank you so much, i will try this tomorrow ! 